# Make `insert` follow `(delete-selection-mode t)`

Tags: helm, region, insert, selection

When I call `helm-copy-to-buffer` (which calls `insert`) with active region in my current buffer, the marked helm candidate is added after the active region.  But I expect the active region to be replaced by the helm candidate, as I had `(delete-selection-mode t)` in my init.el.

I tried to fix it by following advice:

```
(defun delete-region-before-insert (orig-fun &rest args) (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'insert) (lambda (arg) (if (region-active-p) (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))) (insert arg)))) (apply orig-fun args)))
(advice-add 'helm-copy-to-buffer :around #'delete-region-before-insert)
```

But it doesn't change anything, so I have to redefine `helm-copy-to-buffer` to fix it:

```
(defun helm-copy-to-buffer ()
  "Copy selection or marked candidates to `helm-current-buffer'.
Note that the real values of candidates are copied and not the
display values."
  (interactive)
  (with-helm-alive-p
    (helm-run-after-exit
     (lambda (cands)
       (with-helm-current-buffer
         (if (region-active-p) (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))  ; added to delete region if any.
         (insert (mapconcat (lambda (c)
                              (format "%s" c))
                            cands "\n"))))
     (helm-marked-candidates))))
```

Is there any better way to fix it?

In general, how to make sure `insert` comply with `(delete-selection-mode t)`?

Comment: I would recommend typing `M-x find-library RET delsel RET` and then scroll down towards the end have a look at the lines `(put SYMBOL PROPNAME VALUE)`.  Then, have a look at the doc-string for the function `delete-selection-helper`.  I don't use `helm`, but would imagine you just need something like `(put 'your-function 't)` or `(put 'your-function 'yank)` or `(put 'your-function 'supersede)` or `(put 'your-function 'kill)` or `(put 'your-function 'FUNCTION)`.  You may not need anything else other than that one-liner, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've tried `(put 'helm-copy-to-buffer 'delete-selection t)`, `... 'yank` and `... 'supersede`.  All didn't work.  I guess it's because `helm-copy-to-buffer` uses `helm-run-after-exit` to insert string in another buffer.